# Can't pause video in firefox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5-video, mediaelement.js

HTML:

```
<video class="0" autoplay="true" width="586px" height="440" src=""></video>
```

JS:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer();

if($('video').attr('class') == "0"){
    $('video')[0].player.pause();
}
```

In chrome the video is paused correctly. However in firefox it is not paused. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pause your video

```
$('video[class="0"]').get(0).pause()
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eyepat/2/edit#javascript,html

On a sidenote classes can't start with an integer http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if($('video').attr('class') == "0"){
    $('video')[0].pause();
}
```

Comment: @ArtWorkAD problem should be somewhere else, from MDN: `While stopping the playback of media is as easy as calling the element's pause() method, the browser keeps downloading the media until the media element is disposed of through garbage collection.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
 $("video").get(0).pause();
```

...

```
<video class='0' id='video_01'
  controls preload='none'  src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm"
  poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png"   

  <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>

function callPause(){  
    if($('video').attr('class') == "0"){
     $("video").get(0).pause();
     }
   return false;
   }
```

Example Fiddle : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mk7h7/)